# Combining Network Visualization Graph and Map in R"

Tags: r, visualization, network-analysis

I want to create a network visualization graph similar to the one attached using R. The existing edgelist contains columns "From" and "To," and the separate data frame "nodeInfo" contains information about nodes' names, sizes, latitudes, and longitudes. Please assist in creating a graph that meets the following conditions:

1, Create a network visualization graph based on the edgelist. The size of each node should be proportional to the values in "nodeInfo$size."
2, If there are duplicate combinations of "From" and "To" in the edgelist, display multiple edges between two nodes (ex. using techniques like curving the edges).
3, Include isolates in the graph. Isolates are nodes that exist in "nodeInfo" but are not mentioned in the edgelist.
4, Place nodes on an actual map according to the "nodeInfo$longitude" and "nodeInfo$latitude" values. Use a simple and free-to-use map service that is suitable for academic purposes, without relying on paid services like Google Maps API.

```
set.seed(42) 
nodes <- LETTERS[1:9]
from <- sample(nodes, 7, replace = TRUE)
to <- sample(nodes, 7, replace = TRUE)
edgelist <- data.frame(from, to)

nodeInfo <- data.frame(
  name = nodes,
  size = sample(1:10, 9, replace = TRUE),
  longitude = runif(9, min = 135, max = 145),
  latitude = runif(9, min = 30, max = 40)     
)
```

I used the "sna" package to create a network using the following code, but I couldn't overlay it on a map, and I also couldn't perform more complex and detailed tasks. If there are better methods using other packages, I truly appreciate it.

```
library(sna)
edgeNet <- network(edgelist, matrix.type = "edgelist", loops = TRUE, directed = FALSE, vertices = nodeInfo, multiple = T)
 gplot(edgeNet,xlab="EXample",edge.col ="blue", vertex.col="gray",vertex.cex=nodeInfo$size, usearrows=F, edge.lwd = 0.5, edge.lty = "solid",displaylabels=T,label.cex=0.6)
```

Comment: This post could be a startingpoint https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172606/how-to-use-igraph-with-leaflet-for-r

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of plotting options if you move to the `tidygraph` / `ggraph` ecosystem.

Firstly, get your map from `ggmap::get_stamenmap`, which is a free service, and turn it into a long-format data frame. We will opt for a simple line map to make a clean, modern graphic:

```r
library(ggmap)

m <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left = 130, right = 150, bottom = 30, top = 45),
                   zoom = 6, maptype = "toner-background")

r <- cbind(expand.grid(longitude = seq(130, 150, len = ncol(m)),
                       latitude = seq(45, 30, len = nrow(m))),
           fill = c(m))
```

Now you create your graph with the node dataframe and edgelist. Rather than using random points dotted about the map of Japan, let's use three cities.

```r
set.seed(42) 
nodes <- rep(c("Tokyo", "Sapporo", "Osaka"))
from <- sample(nodes, 20, replace = TRUE)
to <- sample(nodes, 20, replace = TRUE)
edgelist <- data.frame(from, to)

nodeInfo <- data.frame(
  name = nodes,
  size = c(14, 1.5, 2.7),
  longitude = c(139.7, 141.4, 135.5),
  latitude =  c(35.7, 43.1, 34.7)   
)
```

It's very easy to turn the node data and edgelist into a tidy graph:

```
library(tidygraph)

g <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodeInfo, edges = edgelist)
```

Finally, we plot the graph, ensuring that we first add the map as a raster layer.

```r
library(ggraph)

ggraph(g, "manual", x = nodeInfo$longitude, 
       y = nodeInfo$latitude) +
  geom_raster(data = r, aes(longitude, latitude, fill = fill), alpha = 0.2) + 
  scale_fill_identity() +
  geom_edge_fan(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = name, size = size))  +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), nudge_x = c(1.2, -1.2, -1.2), size = 6) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = nrow(m)/ncol(m), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 10)) +
  theme_void() +
  guides(size = "none", colour = "none")
```

[image]

There are many customizable options. We can select a different type of stamen map such as "terrain-background", and different ways to connect the nodes:

[image]

Comment: Hi Allan, Thank you for providing detailed instructions. With your code, I was able to complete the graph I wanted to create. Much appreciated.